# How to retrieve primary keys in a table as a simple array in Phalcon?

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I have a table called `users` with primary key on `usr_id`. I want to retrieve all `usr_id` from the table as an arry.

I tried

```
$alluserid= $user->find(array(
   "columns" => "usr_id"
))->toArray();
```

How can I change `$targetId` into a simple array like `Array(1,2,3,4)` instead of

```
Array( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [usr_id] => 37
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [usr_id] => 36
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$alluserid= $user->find(array(
   "columns" => "usr_id"
))->toArray();

var_dump(array_column($alluserid, 'usr_id'));
```